# Julia immutable struct with mutable list

Tags: julia, immutability

Here's some *broken* code:

```
struct NumberedList
  index::Int64
  values::Vector{Int64}

  NumberedList(i) = new(i, Int64[])
end

function set_values!(list::NumberedList, new_values::Vector{Int64})
  list.values = new_values
end

# ---
mylist = NumberedList(1)
set_values!(mylist, [1, 2, 3])
```

I don't want to do either of these:

1. I could declare the `NumberedList` as a `mutable struct` (making *everything* mutable)
2. I could replace `set_values!` with something like this (copy all the values):

```
function set_values!(list::NumberedList, new_values::Vector{Int64})
  for i in new_values
      push!(list.values, i)
  end
end
```

**But I'd like to** make `index` immutable, but allow `values` to be assigned to.

---

Other notes:

- Thread from the Discourse: "[*Mutable field in immutable type*](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/mutable-field-in-immutable-type/3103)," but this doesn't apply to vectors in this setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you want to mutate.

1. If you really want to reassign the field `values::Vector{Int64}` itself, then you have to use a `mutable struct`. There's no way around that, because the actual data of the struct changes when you reassign that field.
2. If you use an immutable struct with a `values::Vector{Int64}` field, it means that you cannot change *which* array is contained, but the array itself is mutable and can change its elements (which are not stored in the struct). In this case, you really do have to copy values to it from external arrays, like your example code (though I would point out that your code did not reset the array to an empty one). I personally think this would be cleaner:

```
function set_values!(list::NumberedList, new_values::Vector{Int64})
  empty!(list.values) # reset list.values to Int64[]
  append!(list.values, new_values)
end
```

3. The thread you linked talks about using `Base.Ref`. `Base.Ref` is pretty much THE way to make a field of an immutable struct indirectly act like a mutable field. It works like this: the field cannot change *which* `RefValue{Vector{Int64}}` instance is contained, but the instance itself is mutable and can change its reference (again, not stored in the struct) to any `Int64` array. You have to use indexing `values[]` to get to the array, though:

```
struct NumberedList
  index::Int64
  values::Ref{Vector{Int64}}

  NumberedList(i) = new(i, Int64[])
end

function set_values!(list::NumberedList, new_values::Vector{Int64})
  list.values[] = new_values # "reassign" different array to Ref
end

# ---
mylist = NumberedList(1)
set_values!(mylist, [1, 2, 3])
```